# Console RPG Game - Attack and Health Functions - C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a console based RPG game that has characters with health, defense, attack power, and armor.  The idea is you select what class you want to play, and then select which enemy you'd like to attack.  Each class has its own values for health, defense, and armor, but attack and defense are based on rolls.

The formula for modifying hit points should be ((Attack roll - Defense roll) - Armor).

edit: I figured out how to handle using the attack damage from one class vs the defense in the other class:

base class declaration:

```
        virtual void attack(Character* c1, Character* c2){}
```

This could probably be made pure virtual to allow for 2 v 1, etc.

my attack function as follows:

```
        void attack(Character* c1, Character* c2){

        double tdmg, hp, arm, tots;

        hp = c1->health(); //set health to current health
        tdmg = (c2->getap() - c1->getd()); //set tdmg to attack power - defense
        tots = tdmg - c1->getarm(); //set tots to tdmg - armor
```

The function call in int main():

```
barba->attack(gobs, barba);
```

I have various get/set functions for attack power, health and defense as well.  Thanks to everyone for the help.  I'd be happy to share the full code when i'm done.  Its very basic i'm afraid.

Comment: _"but I don't think its working. Is there something with my syntax?"_ what are your compiler messages?

Comment: We need a little more information than you "don't think its working". What behavior do you expect? What behavior do you actually get? For some input, what is the expected and actual output? Have you tried stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger? And if you have compiler errors, then please include all of them, verbatim, unedited and complete.

Comment: _"I don't think its working"_ - Then write some unit tests to validate the functionality is correct.

Comment: I edited the post.  I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go through the whole code, but at first glance it seems the problem you are having is that instead of modifying the member variable of the class you modify the input argument:

```
void modHP(int hp, int ap, int dp, int arp)
{
      hp = ((ap - dp) - arp);
}
```

This should probably be:

```
void modHP( const int ap, const int dp, const int arp)
{
      hitpoints = ((ap - dp) - arp);
}
```

Note that i also added const modifiers to the arguments.

If you want a function that calculates the new value of HP based on its old value and the attack and so on it should do that by returning the value:

```
int modHP(int hp, int ap, int dp, int arp)
{
   return hp - ((ap - dp) - arp);
}
```

In this case you should make this function a static member of the class as it doesn't require an instance of the class to do its job. If you have further questions feel free to ask them in comments.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Since it is a static member, I shouldn't have the pointer to call for it?  Right now I have it as:   gobs->modHP(ap, dp, arp, hp);

Comment: No matter what I do, I can't get the HP to subtract correctly.  I don't know why i'm have such an issue.

Comment: When you call the `gobs->setHP(hp)` it doesnt modify the goblins hp because the value of `hp` is never changed (at least not in the code i see). So you set the goblins hp to whatever value is in hp, which i suspect is the original hp of the goblin...

Comment: Thanks I finally figured out how to handle it. Will edit my post.